# Application Insights - track custom event with an array of data as property

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a webapp with search functionality.

I want to be able to track a search event with a list of keywords that were looked for (in order to be able to identify most common keywords).

I currently track data as follows:

```
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(Names.RepositorySearch, new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {PropertyKeys.OrganizationName, repositoryQueryParameter.OrganizationName},
                    {PropertyKeys.RepositoryName, repositoryQueryParameter.RepositoryName},
                    {PropertyKeys.Query, query },
                    {PropertyKeys.IsRegex, isRegex.ToString()},
                    {PropertyKeys.ResultsCount, resultsCount.ToString()},
                    {PropertyKeys.QueryExecutionTime, elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()},
                });
```

I track a full query, which is a bit different than list of tokens/keywords.

I know I could just post another little event for each keyword in a loop, but that seems nasty...

Comment: I posted a very general answer. If you can clarify what you want to do with the data (for example, do you want to write a Kusto query to find searches that include a specific term?), I might be able to give more specific suggestions.

Comment: @xander - for now I intend to create a simple piechart with most frequently used keyword... I suppose that your answer should be suffient (+1, cannot test right now, will accept once confirmed)

Answer (score 2):

If you JSON-encode the search parameters, then you can use the [extract_json()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) function to unpack them in a Kusto query.

Tracking code:

```cs
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(
    "RepositorySearch",
    new Dictionary<string,string> {
        // JSON literal used for example purposes.
        // Use your favorite JSON serializer in real life.
        ["SearchTerms"] = "[ \"Term1\", \"Term2\" ]",
    }
);
```

Kusto query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "RepositorySearch" 
| extend searchTerms = parse_json(customDimensions.SearchTerms)
```

Some of the App Insights data visualizers are smart enough to recognize and render JSON lists/objects nicely automatically. If you just want to visually inspect the data, a custom query might not even be necessary.